# How can I use the containers offer by webdevops/*?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

I'm learning about **Docker Containers**, so, I found [this repo](https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile) with a lot of images and references, can anyone help me in order to understand how can I use those images?

I know the `docker run --rm` command

Answer (score 0):

With docker you first need a docker image. A docker image is a representation of an application that docker can understand and run.
The most common ways to get one is to use `docker pull` or to generate yours with `docker build`.

You can check the images you got with `docker images`

Once you got your image you can run it with `docker run MyImage`, this will create a container, a container is a running application.

Comment: Thank you, I know that. The question is. I have [this image](https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile/blob/master/docker/bootstrap/centos-7/Dockerfile)  I've created and run the container, so how can I know what that container does? Or how can I use that container? am I clear?

Comment: There are no CMD instruction in the dockerfile so it doesn't do anything when you run it. Since it's an image based on centos 7, you can interact with it through a terminal by typing this command `docker run -it YourImage /bin/bash` if that was what you asked.